# How to add a border around an Expanded or Spacer widget? - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add a border around an `Expanded` or `Spacer` using a `Container`.
Apparently, these are supposed to be inside a `Flex` widget, but I don't know to add a border around a `Flex`. The following code throws a `FlutterError`:

```
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
      child: Spacer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add an image that you like to archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cas's answer is not correct, but it did lead me in the right direction. Simply putting an `Expanded` around the `Container` doesn't work; the `Spacer` still needs a flex, and now the `Expanded` also needs a flex. Adding a `Column` as the direct parent of the `Expanded` satisfies the `Expanded`'s requirement for a `Flex` parent, but we must also create a `Column` inside the Container and around the `Spacer`. At this point we have the following in our build method:

```
return Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Spacer(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

It turns out that there is no need for the `Column` and `Expanded` to precede the `Container` if the `Container` is the only child in the `Column`, as this still works:

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Spacer(),
    ],
  ),
);
```

To make a long story short, do both of these:

• put **all** widgets that (contain a `Spacer`/`Expanded` descendant and are **directly** inside a `Flex`) **directly** inside an `Expanded` that is a direct child of that `Flex`

• ensure that **all** `Spacer`/`Expanded` widgets are **directly** inside a `Flex`

Answer (score 0):

`Expanded` and similar widgets have to be inside a flex container, you can just put your `Container` as a direct child of the `Expanded` widget. the container will fill up all the expanded space so your border should work fine.